# SceneKit – How to update an "SCNGeometry"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, scenekit

I load a scene from a .dae file, which is not animated :

```
scene = [SCNScene sceneNamed:@"TestArm.dae"];
```

With some gesture i applied a rotation and translation on my root node :

```
[scene.rootNode convertPosition:SCNVector3Make(movetoX,movetoY,0) toNode:nil];
```

It works like a charm, it's awesome.
But now i need to extract all SCNGeometry from the current displayed node.
This is a big challenge because the SCNGeometry doesn't update when i applied some changement on the node or even animations.

How can I update the SCNGeometry of my node ?

It seems totally impossible.
Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

I have tried to applied some math calculs on all vertices with rotation, transformation, and scale for each SCNNode. -> doesn't work, maybe i don't have the good calcul.

**Edit**

This is my current code for change my geometry node.

```
SCNNode *currentChildren = [[self.childrens objectAtIndex:self.currentIndexParent] objectAtIndex:self.currentIndexChild];

Vertex *v1 = [self.vectrices objectAtIndex:buff[0]];
v1.x = (currentChildren.transform.m11 * v1.x) + (currentChildren.transform.m12 * v1.x) + (currentChildren.transform.m13 * v1.x) + currentChildren.transform.m14;
v1.y = (currentChildren.transform.m21 * v1.y) + (currentChildren.transform.m22 * v1.y) + (currentChildren.transform.m23 * v1.y) + currentChildren.transform.m24;
v1.z = (currentChildren.transform.m31 * v1.z) + (currentChildren.transform.m32 * v1.z) + (currentChildren.transform.m33 * v1.z) + currentChildren.transform.m34;

Vertex *v2 = [self.vectrices objectAtIndex:buff[1]];
v2.x = (currentChildren.transform.m11 * v2.x) + (currentChildren.transform.m12 * v2.x) + (currentChildren.transform.m13 * v2.x) + currentChildren.transform.m14;
v2.y = (currentChildren.transform.m21 * v2.y) + (currentChildren.transform.m22 * v2.y) + (currentChildren.transform.m23 * v2.y) + currentChildren.transform.m24;
v2.z = (currentChildren.transform.m31 * v2.z) + (currentChildren.transform.m32 * v2.z) + (currentChildren.transform.m33 * v2.z) + currentChildren.transform.m34;

Vertex *v3 = [self.vectrices objectAtIndex:buff[2]];
v3.x = (currentChildren.transform.m11 * v3.x) + (currentChildren.transform.m12 * v3.x) + (currentChildren.transform.m13 * v3.x) + currentChildren.transform.m14;
v3.y = (currentChildren.transform.m21 * v3.y) + (currentChildren.transform.m22 * v3.y) + (currentChildren.transform.m23 * v3.y) + currentChildren.transform.m24;
v3.z = (currentChildren.transform.m31 * v3.z) + (currentChildren.transform.m32 * v3.z) + (currentChildren.transform.m33 * v3.z) + currentChildren.transform.m34;
```

**Edit**
I change some code, but still doesn't work.

```
for (int index = 0; index < 3; index++) {
    Vertex *currentVertex = [self.vectrices objectAtIndex:buff[index]];
    currentVertex.x = (currentChildren.presentationNode.worldTransform.m11 * currentVertex.x) + (currentChildren.presentationNode.worldTransform.m12 * currentVertex.x) + (currentChildren.presentationNode.worldTransform.m13 * currentVertex.x) + currentChildren.presentationNode.worldTransform.m14;
    currentVertex.y = (currentChildren.presentationNode.worldTransform.m11 * currentVertex.y) + (currentChildren.presentationNode.worldTransform.m12 * currentVertex.y) + (currentChildren.presentationNode.worldTransform.m13 * currentVertex.y) + currentChildren.presentationNode.worldTransform.m24;
    currentVertex.z = (currentChildren.presentationNode.worldTransform.m11 * currentVertex.z) + (currentChildren.presentationNode.worldTransform.m12 * currentVertex.z) + (currentChildren.presentationNode.worldTransform.m13 * currentVertex.z) + currentChildren.presentationNode.worldTransform.m34;
}
```

It seems like the transformation or worldTransformation on my node, don't update when i apply a mouvement with bones.

I am building a solution for this problem, this my current progress : [github project](https://github.com/remirobert/ObjExporter)

Comment: **Why** are you trying to update the geometry? It is a very uncommon thing to do. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I manipulate my object with rotation, scale, and translation, so my geometry needs to be changed. In fact i want to export a current not in obj file.

Comment: Also, this is your fourth questions in a row that is asking pretty much the same thing. Please don't post duplicate questions. Instead, see if you can edit the existing question to clarify and provide more information about what you are trying to do, what you have tried, and why that didn't work for you.

Comment: Please include your current code for the rest math you are applying to the vertices.

Comment: And what are you doing to save those changes (i.e. to create a new geometry element using a new source)?

Comment: No i have a array of my vertex, and the i wrote them in my obj file directly. It doesn't work.

Comment: Can i use writeToURL:options:delegate:progressHandler on iOS ?